# App Store Server API: invoice lookup api return 404

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, storekit

Per [wwdc21 doc](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10175), one new API of invoice lookup is added. `/inApps/v1/lookup/{customer_order_id}`

[image]

However, we got `404` from prod environment URL.

`curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' "https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/lookup/MN04TZ5XXX"`

```
< HTTP/2 404
< server: daiquiri/3.0.0
< date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 12:03:24 GMT
< content-length: 0
< x-apple-jingle-correlation-key: EJJPZLFC7B3NTSO3PLZNUVVIXY
< x-apple-request-uuid: 2252fcac-a2f8-76d9-c9db-7af2da56a8be
< b3: 2252fcaca2f876d9c9db7af2da56a8be-ad831e3618544a32
< x-b3-traceid: 2252fcaca2f876d9c9db7af2da56a8be
< x-b3-spanid: ad831e3618544a32
< apple-seq: 0.0
< apple-tk: false
< apple-originating-system: CommerceGateway
< x-responding-instance: CommerceGateway:010116:::
< apple-timing-app: 0 ms
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< x-daiquiri-instance: daiquiri:45824002:st44p00it-hyhk15104701:7987:21HOTFIX14
<
```

We try to send this API in the sandbox environment, however, it seems we cannot get the customer order id for the sandbox receipt.

How to invoke this API correctly? and how to do it in a sandbox environment?

Answer (score 0):

The [Order ID Lookup api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/look_up_order_id?changes=latest_major) was added recently.

> Get a customer’s in-app purchases from a receipt using the order ID.
>
> `GET https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/lookup/{orderId}`
>
> Call this endpoint to identify and validate a customer’s in-app purchases, based on their order ID.
>
> When a customer contacts you for support, ask for their order ID and use that value to call this endpoint. Customers can retrieve their order ID’s from their purchase history on the App Store; for more information, see See your purchase history for the App Store, iTunes store, and more. The App Store also sends customers an email receipt with an order ID each time they make in-app purchases.